# An (n)curses-based debugger frontend?

Tags: linux, software-development, debugging

I don't like purely command-line debuggers all that much; but sometimes I'm using a machine which simply does not have any X-based applications nor anything with another kind of GUI, and I'm restricted to a terminal session.

I'm thus interested in a debugger with (n)curses as the user interface - something which will let me watch the source as is go up the stack trace without constantly having to type commands, etc. It doesn't have to be fancy; so something like the ncurses analog of, say, kdbg would be relevant.

Required:

- Libre license.
- Gratis.
- Supports gdb
- Speedy
- Usable with C and C++ code

Desirable:

- Support for other compiled languages
- Supports LLVM's debugger as well as gdb
- Some sort of index / parsing of code / etc. which would enable moving from use to definition, or between definition and declaration
- Under actively development
- Ability to interact with the UI in ways other than typing in commands on some command-line. (i.e. not just a fancier state display over the gdb/llvm debugger command line).

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla GDB satisfies you constraints. [`gdb -tui`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html) is based on curses.

[image]

Also, GDB is capable of advanced customization using `.gdbinit`. You might get inspired by these ones:

- https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard
- https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit

Some people prefer [cgdb](http://cgdb.github.io/) to GDB TUI.

[image]

For more options, see [How to highlight and color gdb output during interactive debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209534/2157640) on Stack Overflow. The screenshots are taken from there.

Comment: But aren't all of these still based on entering commands on the command line?

Comment: Cgdb lists ["visual breakpoint setting"](http://cgdb.github.io/docs/cgdb.html#Source-Window), ["keyboard shortcuts for common functions"](http://cgdb.github.io/docs/cgdb.html#Controlling-CGDB) and ["key mappings (macros)"](http://cgdb.github.io/docs/cgdb.html#Key-User-Interface) among its features. Its interface is very Vim-like.

Comment: GDB TUI has [Single-Key Mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Single-Key-Mode.html#TUI-Single-Key-Mode) where commen debuging tasks take just a single key press. Still, some commands are needed, e.g. to set a breakpoint.

Comment: So, I've upvoted this answer, and it's obviously very useful compared to plain-vanilla gdb use, but I'm still hoping for an answer that's less dependent on a command line.

Comment: I heard about [Clewn](http://clewn.sourceforge.net/), which enables using Vim as an interface to GDB. I'm planning to give it a ride some time. It has the potential to enable tighter integration and more shortcut-driven interface. Still, GDB is such an advanced tool that evading all its commands may not be the most comfortable way to get things done.